# Calculate time duration based on a series in a column when the series changes

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

I have a table consists of 5 columns and millions of rows. I want to capture the start and end times when the Scrap column is true (1) to calculate the total duration in minutes.
•   Start Scrap-Time is when the value in the Scrap column changes from 0 to 1
•   Scrap End Time is when the value in the Scrap column changes from 1 to 0.

I am an MS SQL server 2016

Answer (score 3):

This is a type of gap-and-islands problem.  You can assign groups to the rows using a cumulative sum of `scrap = 0` and then aggregation:

```
select min(timestamp), max(timetamp),
       datediff(minute, min(timestamp), max(timestamp)) as minutes,
       max(velocity) as velocity,
       scrap,
       max(run) as run,
       max(length) as length
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when scrap = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by order by timestamp) as grp
      from t
     ) t
where scrap = 1
group by grp;
```